# Can't load DLL due to dependency issue with Visual C Runtime DLL

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I'm trying load a 3rd party DLL but I get an error when attempting to load it.  Opening it in Dependency Walker shows that the DLL simply relies on kernel32.dll and msvcr90.dll.  However, I get the following error in Dependency Walker when opening this DLL: `Error The Side-by-Side configuration information for [full path to the dll that I am loading] contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001).`

The only copy of msvcr90.dll that exists on the system is one that I copied into the directory that contains my third party DLL.  I ran into a very similar problem on another machine and installing the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable package from Microsoft fixed it. However, I really need to get to the bottom of this as I can't install the redistributable package on all machines that I need this to run on.

I've also tried opening the third party DLL in Visual Studio and examined its manifest.  In it I can see that it explicitly is dependent upon the SP0 version of the Visual C Runtime library:

```
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
```

However, copying that exact version of the DLL to the machine with the problem still doesn't fix it.  What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to include a copy of the Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest file.  Normally, you can get this from the [Visual Studio 9.0 install dir]\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT directory.  However, I had SP1 of Visual Studio installed which had slightly different versions of these files.  I ultimately extracted the appropriate file from the redistributable package from MS.  Obviously if I had another 3rd party DLL that depended upon a different version of the msvcr90.dll I would be in trouble.  I guess this is why Microsoft created the side-by-side thing to begin with.

In short (for any potential Googlers in the future), you have two options:

- Install the Visual C++ 2008
  Redistributable package (just Google
  that term, you'll find it)
- Or manually copy the necessary DLLs
  to your application directory
  including the .manifest file

Comment: If you create an installer for your application then (depending on the installer creation tool you use) this should automatically pull in the appropriate dlls or use the correct merge modules.  That's usually a bit less error-prone than manually copying dlls -- which may conflict with the windows SxS (side-by-side) installation.

Another alternative is to statically link against the runtime, though this may not always be practical.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually probably a more correct answer than mine.  I'll look into what is involved with packing a merge module with my install system.  Up until now the software has been xcopy deployable which was nice in some configurations.